# Vary the colors of same-series data markers in a chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

Hello I have a Column Chart in SSRS . There is only **one** data series. I want to give green color for top 4 and blue colors for the rest ones in this series as you can see in the picture.This is an image that ı want to make but when ı prepare a "*custompalettecolors*" it still gives all the column same color.(I think this is for charts with different series but ı have only one series and many columns).So can you give me some advice for this ?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can by using a formula in the fill if you have someway in the data to specify the top 4.  On fill properties for the series:
[image]

Now the question is: What goes in the formula?  You'll need something in your data that ranks the items.  so, that you could create a formula like this:

`=iif(Fields!Ranking.Value<=4,"Green","Blue")`

I would do this in my T-SQL.  Not seeing your dataset, I can't tell you exactly how to proceed. I hope this gets you started

Comment: Thanks , I got the solution from my manager but you gave the same answer 